# Incorrect syntax near 'int' when using updatecommand on a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource, sqlexception, updatecommand

I have a problem that when ever I try to update a record in the database using gridview update event handler and an updatecommand in sqldatascource
I get the following exception
Incorrect syntax near 'int'.
the weird thing is when I reload the page I find that the record was updated successfully but yet I need this exception message not to appear what should I do

update event handler

```
   protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            int BusId = Convert.ToInt32(((DataKey)GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]).Value);
            TextBox Capacity =(TextBox) row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
            TextBox DriverName =(TextBox) row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
            TextBox Phone =(TextBox) row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("capaity", Capacity.Text);
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("id", BusId.ToString());
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("driver", DriverName.Text);
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters.Add("phone", Phone.Text);
            SqlDataSource1.Update();
    }
```

gridview asp.net code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Bus Number" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="326px" Width="1017px" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Bus Number" HeaderText="Bus Number" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Bus Number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Capacity" HeaderText="Capacity" SortExpression="Capacity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NumberOfBooking" HeaderText="NumberOfBooking" SortExpression="NumberOfBooking" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Driver" HeaderText="Driver" SortExpression="Driver" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" ShowHeader="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date Added" HeaderText="Date Added" SortExpression="Date Added" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

the updatecommand

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE Buses SET Capacity = @capaity WHERE VechileId = @id ;UPDATE Vechile SET Driver = @driver, Phone = @phone  
 WHERE VechileId = @id">
```

Comment: Try adding semicolon between both update statements.

Comment: already tried 
didn't work

Comment: Please debug the code and show us the actual UpdateCommand you are getting.

Comment: I ran the debugger and here's the update command in the sqldatascource
`UPDATE Buses SET Capacity = @capaity WHERE VechileId = @id;UPDATE Vechile SET Driver = @driver,Phone = @phone WHERE VechileId = @id` @Microsoft

Comment: And what values you are getting for capaity, id, driver, phone. Your update command seems to be fine. There must be problem with these parameters. Also, your id property seems to be of type integer and your parameter uses  BusId.ToString() if this is the problem then please try Convert.ToInt32(BusId)